# How to revert VLC media player to its original state?

Tags: vlc

For the last few days, my VLC media player has not been responding at all. When I try to double click any file or even run VLC media player without any file, it just doesn't open up.

I tried to open it through terminal, and it was working fine, but there were no option coming on the VLC media player screen and also if I close the terminal, VLC media player closes automatically. How do I make VLC media player back to its original way so that I can access any file through VLC media player?

Answer (score 19):

You can reset your VLC media player settings by renaming your current VLC media player configuration folder. 
 Execute the following command in a terminal:

```
mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc.old
```

If VLC media player  still does not open correctly you can try reinstalling VLC media player:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Before running VLC media player , make sure it is not still running:

```
ps ax | grep vlc
```

This should not return anything. If it does execute the commands below until the `ps` command keeps quiet (does not return anything any more). Start with the first, and then use the next until it gets killed successfully:

1. `pkill vlc`
2. `killall vlc`
3. `killall -9 vlc`

**Notes**:

- You can probably delete your old configuration folder with `rm -rf ~/.config/vlc.old`.

Comment: i am not able to kill running vlc....Is there any way to force kill it through terminal??

Comment: I updated the answer to add the kill commands. Make sure to use the correct pid of the running vlc process.

Comment: Thank dude.... u saved me...actually kill command was not able to stop the process.....i have to use the system monitor....and then after installing it worked....u made my day....cheers...

Comment: I replaced the kill commands with killall which only needs the process name (vlc). The last one should generally kill it.
If this helped you might want to accept the answer, thanks :-).

Comment: Thank you so much. Continue playback was not working and tweaked a few settings and VLC won't open then. Changing .config file worked and continue playback works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

I recently had a similar issue with my VLC and I found a more elegant solution to this problem and thought I should share it here. 
You can simply reset VLC settings by typing the following in the terminal

```
vlc --reset-config
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[muyisco's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199710/how-to-revert-vlc-media-player-to-its-original-state/342326#342326) worked for me, and it is also on https://wiki.videolan.org.

> In GNU/Linux, delete the `~/.config/vlc` and `~/.cache/vlc` folders or execute **vlc --reset-config** in a terminal.

Old versions of VLC had the data stored in `~/.vlc`.