# I deleted my Home content, how to restore?

Tags: data-recovery, vlc, restore

I tried to reset my vlc configuration by using this commands in the terminal

`vlc --reset-config`

Then when i try to view the documents, downloads, music, pictures and videos folder all files were gone. Please help!

Comment: Which documents?

Comment: Did you run any other commands?

Comment: @Maythux i mean all files in the Files folder..

Comment: You probably do something else

Comment: i only followed the commands here "http://askubuntu.com/questions/199710/how-to-revert-vlc-media-player-to-its-original-state".. @Wilf

Comment: Ok - are you sure you typed the commands correctly (particularly the `rm -rf.....` one), and does `ls -a ~/`, `ls -a ~/Documents`,`ls -a ~/Desktop`  show any of you documents? Depending on the filesystem if you have deleted files I think it is best to use the hard disk as little as possible, and either use recovery tools yourself ([e.g.](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=recover+deleted+files)) or get professional data recovery (may be difficult for linux `ext*` systems).

Comment: @Wilf yes i double checked it the 'rm -rf . . . .' . I did not tried yet the 'ls' one.. do i have to ? what is this command for ?

Comment: On most linux systems using sh and similar: `ls <path>/<to>/<folder>` lists files in a directory (where `~` is the home directory), `rm /<path>/<to>/<file-or-folder>` removes , `mv <path>/<to>/<src> <path>/<to>/<dest>` moves files, `cp <path>/<to>/<src> <path>/<to>/<dest>` copies files. You can get help on what most commands do using `man CMD` (e.g. `man rm`), or `CMD --help` (e.g. `mv --help`).

Comment: @sAizOu Please add the `history` result

Comment: You can also use `history | tail -50` to get the last 50 commands run, then please can you [edit] this into your question using [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) :)

Comment: i'm currently using  another computer in an internet cafe.. i jst did a screenshot on my laptop and i'll post it.. @Wilf

Comment: Ok thats fine - if you need a image uploader you can use http://imgur.com and post a link

Comment: @Wilf i'm currently using  another computer in an internet cafe.. maybe i'll just type the history one by one.. here it is: 1 mv ~/ .config/vlc ~/ .config/vlc.old, 2  sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc, 3 sudo apt-get install vlc, 4 ps ax | grep vlc, 5 pkill vlc, 6 killall vlc, 7 killall -9 vlc, 8 rm -rf ~/ .config/vlc.old, 9 vlc --reset-config, 10 sudo shutdown -r now, 11 ls -a ~/, 12 ls -a ~/Documents, 13 ls -a ~/Desktop, 14 ls -a ~/Videos, 15 history | tail -50

Comment: @Wilf http://imgur.com/1VTMFrQ

Comment: @Maythux http://imgur.com/1VTMFrQ

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Here your problem command number 8:

```
rm ~/ .config/vlc.old
```

What did you do here?

When a space exists between a path the command consider it another option, what i mean in the aboce command you ask system to delete all files under your home `~/` and delete the folder `.config/vlc.old`.

The correct command have to be like that:

```
 rm ~/.config/vlc.old
```

For that it's better always to use quotes ' ' within path such as

```
 rm '~/.config/vlc.old'
```

#### Now how to solve it?

If you need the data was in your home then you should have some data recovery. Take a look on my answer :https://askubuntu.com/a/638497/150504

If you don't need that files and you just want your ["well known" user directories](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) like the desktop folder and the music folder, you can restore by loggin out and then login again. If this doesn't work then do this:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Add those lines then save and logout then login:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: doesn't work.. nothing changes.. T_T

Comment: type `cd ~`  first

Comment: still the same does'nt work..

Comment: Do your files appear in the output of `ls -a ~`,`ls ~/.config/vlc/` or `ls ~/.config/vlc.old`? The use of `rm -rf ~/ .config/vlc.old` may mean this more of a data recovery issue...

Comment: it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: It says that for which command?

Comment: ls -a ~ , ls ~/.config/vlc/ or ls ~/.config/vlc.old - this 3 commands..

Comment: output of `ls /home`?

Comment: just the name of my pc.. "bazz-pc"

Comment: ok then `ls -a  /home/bazz-pc`

Comment: http://imgur.com/Q7RVHK4

Comment: Ok here is your dirs again, you can see your folders now

Comment: @Maythux there are still no files in it..

Comment: ok i get the reason wait i'll update my answer again,